# Regex return always false in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have regex like this:

```
(?i)^(?!.*\bWITH\b).*\(\s*.*\s*\b(INDEX|FASTFIRSTROW|HOLDLOCK|SERIALIZABLE|REPEATABLEREAD|READCOMMITTED|READUNCOMMITTED|ROWLOCK|PAGLOCK|TABLOCK|TABLOCKX|NOLOCK|UPDLOCK|XLOCK|READPAST)\b\s*.*\s*\)
```

It return true in http://regexstorm.net.

But when i run in C#, it always return false.

String input to text:

```cs
INNER JOIN t_hat_meisaimidasi AS MM (READCOMMITTED, NOLOCK) WHERE ( AND hat_kanri_no = ?
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Thinking sideways for a moment: the [DacFx package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/) includes a fully featured T-SQL parser (`Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlParser`). This may be more worthwhile in the long term than futzing around with regexes.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and ask folks to stop opining on what *human* language to program in; it isn't pertinent to the question, and the question isn't at all impacted by the choice. Going on and on about it walks a thin line of propriety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returns `true` for me; probably you didn't use `@"..."`, so the escape tokens (`\b` etc) aren't what you think they are:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(
    @"INNER JOIN t_hat_meisaimidasi AS MM (READCOMMITTED, NOLOCK) WHERE ( AND hat_kanri_no = ?",
    @"(?i)^(?!.*\bWITH\b).*\(\s*.*\s*\b(INDEX|FASTFIRSTROW|HOLDLOCK|SERIALIZABLE|REPEATABLEREAD|READCOMMITTED|READUNCOMMITTED|ROWLOCK|PAGLOCK|TABLOCK|TABLOCKX|NOLOCK|UPDLOCK|XLOCK|READPAST)\b\s*.*\s*\)"));
```

Note: `"\b"` is a string of length 1 that contains a backspace character; `@"\b"` is a string of length 2 that contains a slash and a b. When dealing with regex, you **almost always** want to use a verbatim string literal (`@"..."`).

To make it even better: Visual Studio will use colorization to tell you when you're getting it right:

[image]